# Configuration for Clang formatting

Tags: objective-c, clang

I have following objective-C codes written in XCode without any formatting.

```
[Fasttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt showFireStarterAlert:^{
    [self genericClickEvent:@"send"];
} pickFriendsClick:^{
    //sdf
}];
```

Now when i run my clang-formatter, then above code gets converted into following form:

```
[Fasttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt showFireStarterAlert:^{
    [self genericClickEvent:@"send"];
}
                                      pickFriendsClick:^{
                                          //sdf
                                      }];
```

I dont like the formatted code. So i wanted to know that which clang-formatter-setting is doing this undesired formatting, so that even after running clang-formatter, my code alignment doesn't change for such codes. What i think main problem here is that 2nd argument of objective-c method i.e. 'pickFriendsClick' is getting formatted to a new line, and then it moves to far right in order to align colons.